# Expressing a condtion in JBoss Drools

Tags: java, drools, rules, rule-engine, business-rules

I am using JBoss Drools. I have a business requirement as defined below. and I want to convert it into JBoss Drools DRL format.

The Business requirement : I have two sets of location. One is, locations which are visited by user previoulsy. Let's call it as X. This information is obtained at runtime. And I will have some set of locations with me and let's call it as Y. This locations: Y are predefined in the rule that means Y is static. I must have a rule such that if any of the location in X matches with any of the location in Y then it has to invoke some java code.

In algorithmic view

```
rule "Check if Locations X matches with Locations Y"

      When
         X: It Contains locations visted by user previosuly (obtained at runtime)
         Y: It contains some predefined locations
         Check if any location in x matches with any location in Y
     then
         call some java code here to process this.

end;
```

So now, how can I express the above rule in a JBoss-Drools DRL fashion? Any help on this regard is really appreciated.

Comment: Could you clarify the problem you are trying to solve? In particular, please show us the class definitions of the facts you are operating on.

Comment: I modified my question a bit. I don't have any class that handles facts.Let me know if you need any details from me.

Comment: Facts are the objects that you match in your `when`-clause, such as `SuperSet` and `Set<String>`. I still do not fully understand your question. Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish in prose instead of pseudocode?

Comment: I have to define a rule such that it contains a location name. In runtime I will pass a set of locations as a List of Strings to this rule and if the location mentioned in the rule matches with any of the passed locations I have to enter into the then block and need to invoke a java code. Hope this explains my question.

Comment: So the way I would do this in Drools is to insert all the locations in the set as individual facts using `StatefulKnowledgeSession.insert()`. A fact is usually represented as a Bean, so you will need to implement a wrapper `class Location` that contains an identifying `String`. Then you can write a rule that matches for a specific `Location` and invokes a method on it. Does that make sense to you? Does that cover your requirements?

Comment: Lets say instead of matching to a single location, If I want to match with multiple locations can I do this. Could you please give a simple example in DRL format?

Comment: I don't think I understand your requirements enough in order to formulate a concrete rule. How exactly should matching for multiple locations work? You previously mentioned that you want a rule that checks the input facts for a single location, now you tell me you need to somehow match multiple locations. If you can state your requirements in concrete terms (i.e. the actual business requirement) instead of abstractly, I am confident that you will be able to reformulate your question in such a way that it can actually  be answered.

Comment: The Business requirement is as followed: I have two sets of location. One is, locations which are visited by user previoulsy. Let's call it as X. And I will have some set of locations with me and let's call it as Y. If User visited any location present in Y previously I will have to invoke some java process. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: I modified my question to include my business requirement. If you need any other details please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, so rephrasing this, what you're trying to do is compute set intersection and invoke code if the result is non-empty? Are the locations in Y dynamic as well or are they fixed? Why do you need to do this in Drools instead of Java?

Comment: Locations in Y are fixed. I want to do it in Drools bcz I have lots of such rules to process and in long run these fixed values may become dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I'm ready to give it a try based on your explanations. If this is not quite what you were looking for, we can work towards a more suitable solution. Also, please excuse my limited command of geography ;).

First, I'll define our data model. We have the following fact class that models locations:

```
package de.jannik.locationrules;

public class VisitedLocation {

    private String name;

    public VisitedLocation(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Then, we have a class that models users. We only need this for the method which you want to invoke:

```
package de.jannik.locationrules;

public class User {
    public void handleVisitedContinent(String continentName) {
        System.out.println("User has been to " + continentName + ".");
    }
}
```

Now we can describe the business requirements in terms of these model classes:

```
package de.jannik.drltest

import de.jannik.locationrules.VisitedLocation;
import de.jannik.locationrules.User;

global User user;

rule "User has been to Europe"

    when
        exists VisitedLocation(name in ("Berlin", "Paris", "London", "Rome"))
    then
        user.handleVisitedContinent("Europe");
end

rule "User has been to Australia"

    when
        exists VisitedLocation(name in ("Melbourne", "Sydney"))
    then
        user.handleVisitedContinent("Australia");
end

rule "User has been to America"

    when
        exists VisitedLocation(name in ("San Francisco", "New York", "Buenos Aires"))
    then
        user.handleVisitedContinent("America");
end
```

Here, I have formulated a number of rules that call the `User.handleVisitedContent(String)` method with different arguments depending on which `VisitedLocation`s exist in the working memory. Please note that the user is not modeled explicitly in the facts. Instead, we assume that a new session is created everytime a user needs to be modified. Depending on your business requirements and performance considerations, you may want to change this to use only a single session for all users.

Here is the code I use to execute the rules I have defined:

```
...
@Test
public void testLocationRules() {
    KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();
    kbuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("locations.drl"), ResourceType.DRL);
    if (kbuilder.hasErrors()) {
        KnowledgeBuilderErrors errors = kbuilder.getErrors();
        System.out.println(errors.toString());
        throw new RuntimeException(errors.toString());
    }
    KnowledgeBase knowledgeBase = KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBase();
    knowledgeBase.addKnowledgePackages(kbuilder.getKnowledgePackages());
    StatelessKnowledgeSession session = knowledgeBase.newStatelessKnowledgeSession();
    session.setGlobal("user", new User());
    List<VisitedLocation> facts = new ArrayList<VisitedLocation>();
    facts.add(new VisitedLocation("Berlin"));
    facts.add(new VisitedLocation("Paris"));
    facts.add(new VisitedLocation("San Francisco"));
    facts.add(new VisitedLocation("Saigon"));
    session.execute(facts);
}
...
```

This results in the following output:

```
User has been to America.
User has been to Europe.
```

Please let me know if this is not what you were looking for or if you need further clarification. Also, you may want to consult the [Drools Expert User Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.4.0.CR1/drools-expert-docs/html_single/) for more explanations of Drools concepts.

Comment: Nice to hear that my solution helped you. If you are satisfied with the answer, it would be nice if you awarded me the bounty of 100 reputation.